# I'm trying to increase the number when I click long press button in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to increase the number when I click long press button in android
like snapchat camera!

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use OnLongClickListener and increment the number in it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onLongClickListener` for listening to long presses. Below is some code:

```
btnPlay.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        //increment the counter here
        return true;
    }
});
```